# Charts.newDataTable() not working with Dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-ads-api

From within a Google Ads script, I'm trying to create a basic line chart as described here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/line-chart-builder

The data that I'm looking to chart is Date X Clicks.

I'm able to generate the chart with my data from Google Ads, however, **Dates** are being formatted as **Strings** and not actual dates within the chart which is causing other issues.

For example, this code will work with my data but formats the dates as strings within the chart:

```
var dataBuilder = Charts.newDataTable();  
dataBuilder.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Date');
dataBuilder.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Clicks');
```

When I try this code, it does not work:

```
var dataBuilder = Charts.newDataTable();  
dataBuilder.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, 'Date');
dataBuilder.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Clicks');
```

I have tried to convert the date data from this:
`["2019-09-27",75],["2019-09-29",102],["2019-9-30",112]`

To something like this:
`["new Date(2019,9,27)",75],["new Date(2019,9,29)",102],["new Date(2019,9,30)",112]`

Based on the documentation that I found here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

But that does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, `"Date(2019,9,27)"` does not work. I receive the following error - "Object type does not match column type."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to solve this problem by exporting the Google Ads data to a Google Sheet and then reading that sheet back into Google Ads for the chart.

I did something like this which worked for me:

```
function BuildChart(myMetric, ssName) {

  //Load the spreadsheeet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ssName);

  //Grab all the data in the sheet
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:B29').getValues();

  //Start Building the data table
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, data[0][0]);
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, data[0][1]);

  //Add rows
  for(var j=1; j<data.length; j++){
    Logger.log(data[0][1] + ':' + data[j])
    dataTable.addRow([data[j][0],data[j][1]]);
  }

  //Create and build chart
  var chartBuilder = Charts.newLineChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .setTitle(myMetric + ' over the past 28 days')
      .setXAxisTitle('Date')
      .setYAxisTitle(myMetric)
      .setDimensions(850, 350)
      .setOption('legend.position', 'none')
      .setOption('trendlines', {'type':'linear','color':'purple'})
      .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.NORMAL)
      .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM);      

  var chart = chartBuilder.build();

  return chart;
}
```